# Pymodbus Registers Can Not Decode Correctly

Tags: python, modbus-tcp, pymodbus

```
from pymodbus.payload import BinaryPayloadDecoder
from pymodbus.constants import Endian
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusTcpClient

def convertINT32(data):
       decoder = BinaryPayloadDecoder.fromRegisters(data, Endian.Big, wordorder=Endian.Little)
       return decoder.decode_32bit_int()

client = ModbusTcpClient(host="176.219.182.106", port="502")
client.connect()
data = client.read_holding_registers(address=230,count=10,unit=1)

eaPlus = convertINT32(data.registers[0:2]) # kWh Del
eaNeg = convertINT32(data.registers[2:4])  # kWh Rec
erPlus = convertINT32(data.registers[4:6]) #VARh Del
erNeg = convertINT32(data.registers[6:8])  #kVAR Rec

client.close()

print("Active Energy Plus: %s \nActive Energy Negative: %s \nReactive Energy Plus: %s \nReactive Energy Negative: %s" %(eaPlus,eaNeg, erPlus, erNeg))
print("----------------------------")
print("Register List: %s" % data.registers)
print("----------------------------")
print("Actual values are APPROXİMATE:\nActive Energy Plus: 989 \nActive Energy Negative: 3879077 \nReactive Energy Plus: 268384 \nReactive Energy Negative: 361")
```

I am triyng to read meter values from Schneider ION7650(I doesnt matter if you dont know) and here is a  modbus register list:

[image]

I know exact values and i compare the result with them my code its looks like wrong.  IP address and port is reachable so you can access the meter. What is wrong in here?

And Output:

```
Active Energy Plus: 3867613 
Active Energy Negative: 275048
Reactive Energy Plus: 6270
Reactive Energy Negative: 3866985
----------------------------
Register List: [989, 59, 12904, 4, 6270, 0, 361, 59, 23532, 65535]
----------------------------
Actual values are APPROXİMATE:
Active Energy Plus: 989
Active Energy Negative: 3879077
Reactive Energy Plus: 268384
Reactive Energy Negative: 361
```

Also you can check the values real time values from [here](http://176.219.182.106:82/index.html) then click consumption

Answer (score 1):

I find a solution. When i remove wordoreder from BinaryDecoder.fromregisters its works. Also i saw order list in Modbus Poll. There is a lot of choise like

- A B C D (Byte order: Big Endian)
- D C B A
- C D A B
- B A D C (Byte order: Little Endian)

If i wrong please correct me. How can read other to options. Also what is the word order? Is there a any combination read "C D A B combination like wordorder=Endian.Big byteorder= Endian.Little

Answer (score 0):

From the [Modbus Protocol and Register Map for ION Devices documentation](https://www.se.com/ww/en/download/document/70022-0124-01/) (page 12):

> According to the Modbus protocol, in response to a request for register 4xxxx of a particular slave device, the Modbus master reads register xxxx-1 from the slave. For example, register 40011 corresponds to holding register 10.

Thus set `address` to 229 instead of 230 to read 10 registers starting from address 230. Also, the byteorder and wordorder are both big-endian.

I tried this and got the expected values.